# How to "convert" window.location.pathname from object to string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pathname

I need pathname (www.my-site.com/**this-part/and-this-part/etc/**) in JS/jQuery but I need it as **string** not as object.

In other words I need `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` in JS/jQuery.

I've tried:

```
var page_pathname = location.pathname;

var page_pathname = location.pathname + location.search;

var page_pathname = (location.pathname+location.search).substr(1);
```

---

All I get with `console.log`:

**1.** `Object {error: Object}`

**2.** `Location {hash: "", search: "", pathname: "/my-cat/my-title/", port: "", hostname: "www.my-site.com"…}`

What I need with `console.log`: `my-cat/my-title/`

Comment: I'm unsure of your issue, as `location.pathname` returns a string, not an object`console.log(location.pathname.substr(1))` should work for you.

Comment: @Solo whatever you were trying, you were trying it wrong.  `.pathname` is _always_ a string.

Comment: @Solo it's not an answer. If that solved the problem then this question should probably be deleted or closed as the issue was due to a syntax or typographical issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`window.location.pathname` is already a string.

You can also try:

`String(window.location.pathname)`.

This is explicit conversion to string.

`window.location.href` will also help you in retrieving the full url.

Answer (score 0):

Use to `toString()` method to transform your object to string

Example

```
var currentLocation = location.toString();

console.log(currentLocation);

o/p - "http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33895647/edit"
```